# Automate checking process

Tags: javascript

The code below returns me 'even' or 'odd', but I have to always change, what to do for him to check 25 to 115 and show result in the body of the page?

```html
<html>
    <title>FrontPage</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form method="post" name="Form1" onsubmit="Check();">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="bSubmit"></p>
    </form>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function Check() {
    var n = "26";
    var finish = n/2;
    
    if(n & 1){
        alert("Impar");
    } else {
        alert("Par");
    }
    alert(finish);
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: 1) "check 25 to 115" ...make a loop which runs the same logic on each of these values in turn. A `for` loop would be sensible.  2) "Display in body of page" - google how to add elements to your page using Javascript (or how to append to existing elements)...you can find it out with a quick search. What have you researched or tried so far in relation to your requirements above?

Answer (score 1):

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
var result = document.querySelector('#result');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  for (var i = 25; i <= 115; i++) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerText = i.toString() + ' - ' + ((i & 1) ? 'Impar' : 'Par');
    result.append(li);
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="btn" type="submit" value="Submit" name="bSubmit">
<ul id="result"></ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just implement your code within a for-loop (since you know exactly how many iterations you need):

```js
document.querySelector('#btnSubmit').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var min = 25;
  var max = 115;
  var i;
  for (i = min; i <= max; i += 1) {
    console.log(check(i));
  }
});

function check(n) {
  var s = `${n} is `;
  s += n % 2 === 0 ? "even" : "odd";
  return s;
}

check();
```

```html
<input id="btnSubmit" type="button" value="Check" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [foor](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp) loop like so:

```js
const append = str => document.getElementById('print').innerHTML += str;

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function () {
  for (let i = 25; i <= 115; i++) {
    const result = i % 2 === 0 ? 'even' : 'odd';
    append(`<p>Number ${i} is ${result}</p>`);
  }
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">Result</button>
<div id="print"></div>
```